# Can we have different bundle identifiers for a sticker pack extension and the existing iOS app?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ios10, imessage, ios-extensions

We are about to release a stickers pack extension to our existing iOS app.
This is how I've added the sticker extension to the existing iOS project in xCode 8.
File -> New -> Target -> Sticker Pack Extension.

Bundle identifier for the existing iOS app: com. Company name. Product name

Bundle identifier for the stickers extension: com. Company name. Product name. Sticker app name

Can we have two different bundle identifiers for these two targets and still submit the app as a single package(includes both iOS and Stickers app) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have used two bundle identifiers in this case.

```
Sticker pack's bundle identifer is: iOS App's bundle identifier + Sticker pack name.
```

Since the core bundle identifier is same for both the apps(iOS app and Sticker pack), its working as a single app.
When a user downloads our iOS app, sticker pack is now automatically downloaded and available in their messages drawer.

Answer (score 1):

As long as your apps are bundled, you need to use the parent app to carry the sticker pack. So I'm guessing not. If you're stuck with an existing App ID, create a wildcard App ID and provisioning profiles to connect child apps to your project.